# deduping a list based on a part of a class

Tags: c#

I have a `List<Person>` and want to remove duplicates based on the `NPI` field.

I am struggling to find anything related to this or solving it on my own. Below is the `Person` class. I need to dedupe based on the `NPI` field, but my problem is that some `NPI` fields are blank so I can't have anything that has a blank field show up as a dedupe and remove it from the list.

It doesn't matter which duplicates are removed from the list as long as there are no duplicate NPIs left.

```
class Person
{
    string NPI;
    string Address;

    public string getNPI()
    {
        return NPI;
    }

    public Person(String npi, String address)
    {
        this.NPI = npi;
        this.Address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you're trying to accomplish? Do you have a `List<Person>` and you want to eliminate duplicates based on the `NPI` property?

Comment: so if personA and personB have the same NPI i want to remove it from the list and output it to another one. i need to do this to the entire list tho so i have to compare 600,000 records to 600,000 records

Comment: Which one do you want to remove? Please elaborate by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60763239/edit) the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Also, in your class you have NPI and address as private fields. Is that correct?

Comment: @RufusL does it matter if i have them private for the purpose i am asking about?

Comment: @RufusL i do not currently have them as private in my class

Comment: Then why are they private here? Is there really a `getNPI` method? Please show the actual code so we can help. Currently there is no way to populate a list of `Person` and set the NPI field (outside the `Person` class).

Comment: @RufusL there is my code in the class to set all the properties inside it i didnt think any of that matter to my question

Comment: `var unique = people.GroupBy(p => p.getNPI()).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();`

Comment: @RufusL my problem is there are a lot of records that dont have NPIs so they are blank and then they will match all the blanks as duplicates

Comment: So you want to keep all the blank ones, along with unique ones?

Comment: @bigs89 Please, provide a sample input list of persons (with persons who have empty or null `NPI`) and an expected output for this list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to select all the items that have empty `NPI` fields, along with the unique `NPI` fields from the rest, you can use a `GroupBy` clause along with some checks for blank `NPI` values:

```
var people = new List<Person>
{
    new Person ("dupe", "dupe npi"),
    new Person ("dupe", "another dupe npi"),
    new Person ("", "empty npi"),
    new Person ("", "another empty npi"),
    new Person ("unique", "unique npi")
};

var uniqueAndBlank = people
    .Where(p => string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.getNPI()))      // Get all the empty NPIs
    .Concat(people                                     // Concat with other items
        .Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.getNPI())) // Whose NPIs are set
        .GroupBy(p => p.getNPI())                      // Grouped by their NPI fields
        .Select(g => g.First()))                       // Grab the first item
    .ToList();

// Result:
// {{ "", "empty npi" },
//  { "", "another empty npi" },
//  { "dupe", "dupe npi" },
//  { "unique", "unique npi" }}
```

Comment: thank you i will play around with this to get it to work

Comment: i am using that code but i cannot get it to return any values.  it is finding the proper count but when i try to output the lines of uniqueAndBlank all the values r null.  the other thing is i need to output all the removed duplicates

Comment: The sample I provided works. What is different in your version?

Comment: how are you outputting the results?

Comment: ok i figured out the output part. is there a way to output all the removed records tho?

Comment: nevermind i figured that out too.  thank you so much for all your help!!